# When can we use a colon after a dash?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

This is from The Development of Human Rights Law by the Judges of the International Court of Justice by Shiv R.S. Bedi:

> If, as Prof Brownlie states—:'Sovereignty, or sovereignty and
>   independence, are often the terms used to describe both the legal
>   personality of a state and teh incidents of that personality'—then
>   what would be the effect on sovereignty, or in other words how much
>   would it be conditioned by, of the principle of human dignity which,
>   by already conditioning the State sovereignty in the first instance,
>   has given birth to a new 'legal personality', the individual human
>   being, in the international law?

Can someone tell me when we can use a colon after a dash? I've honestly never seen it and never seen such combination mentioned in a style book.

Comment: That's about typesetting, rather than language, and is thus much more subject to house styles and so on. It's not something there's any general rule about. It's is *damn* weird, though.

Comment: I would have personally used a dash and omitted the colon.

Comment: Why is *sovereignty* misspelled in several places? Is this an exact quote from the original source?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not well punctuated. Although house styles will vary, the colon is used to introduce a quote after a complete sentence:

> Prof. Brownlie has much to say on the relationship between the individual and the state: "Sovereignty, or ..."

In this example, the quote is incorporated into the sentence and so should receive only the same punctuation that it would have had *if it was not a quote*. A comma is required for the parenthetical phrase "as Prof. Bronwnlie states". No other punctuation is required:

> If, as Prof Brownlie states, 'sovereignty, or sovereignty and...'

It is not ungrammatical to use "—:" but it is odd and not needed.